# Center a popup using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center this popup but I can't seem to get it to work properly on smaller screens like iphone. It looks okay on desktop/laptop screens. Can anyone suggest any ideas how to use media queries to get it the popup to be centered properly regardless of screen size? thanks.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #popup {
        display: none;
        background: #FFF;
        border: 5px solid #444;
        padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 20%;
        left:35%;
        width: 25%;
        min-width: 210px;
        z-index: 100000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #popup-overlay {
        display: none;
        background: #000;
        opacity: 0.5;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Post your html markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a transform to centre the element. This will work no matter the width / height of the element

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#popup {
    /*display: none;*/
    background: #FFF;
    border: 5px solid #444;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 210px;
    z-index: 100000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
#popup-overlay {
    /*display: none;*/
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">Look at me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
#popup {
    display: none;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 5px solid #444;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    min-width: 210px;
    z-index: 100000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Note:
It is better to add some jsfiddle like url instead of providing partial details make easy to understand and workout.

Answer (score 0):

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-120px;
```

(210 / 2) + 15 = 120

Answer (score 0):

I would move the object to the center and then to the right the half of its size.

As the object width is not fixed, use `transform` to do that:

```
#popup {
       ...
       left:50%;
       transform: translate(-50%);
       ...
       }
```

Despite `transform` is not available in IE8 and below, may be a good solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/fvLtd068/

Answer (score 0):

For html5 enabled browsers use:

```css
#popup {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 5px solid #444;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    position: fixed;
    /* top: 20%; */ //Remove
    /* left: 35%; */ //Remove
    /* width: 25%; */ //Remove
    left: 50%; // Insert
    top: 50%; // Insert
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); // Insert
    min-width: 210px;
    z-index: 100000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```